First Hello World in C using MacOS and the terminal prompt
I´m doing my first program in C and I don´t now how to compile it to show the message in the terminal.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return 0;
}

Next, in the terminal, I ran the gcc main.c; after that I wrote ./main and then zsh: no such file or directory: ./main.
I´m stuck there.
I'm trying to show the message Hello World! in the terminal.

Instead of ./main try ./a.out. Or make gcc create the executable with whatever name you prefer: gcc -omain main.c

BTW: you don't need <stdlib.h> for this program

gcc main.c -o main then ./main

This question is similar to: Using GCC to compile C code. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The -o option to gcc tells it what to call the executable it produces.  In the absence of a -o option, it defaults to a.out.  Look in your directory and you should see it.

Consider using make main to compile the executable main from main.c.

An aside, but there's need need for your program to #include <stdlib.h>

You haven't told gcc what to name your file, so it uses the default "a.out". You can run this with ./a.out, or if you want to have the executable named "main" use the following command.
gcc main.c -o main

I would additionally strongly suggest you compile with warnings turned on. Warnings are an indication that your code will compile without issue, but probably will not run without issue. Eliminating warnings isn't a 100% guarantee that there aren't bugs in your code, but when you get clues to how to minimize bugs from your compiler, you should heed them.
gcc -Wall -Wextra main.c -o main

And if you want to treat those warnings as errors and force yourself to resolve them, removing the option to ignore them.
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror main.c -o main


Using -Werror is strongly recommended.  If the compiler deigns to generate a warning, it means there is an error in your code — all the time when you're a novice and 99.99% after you've been coding in C for a couple of decades or longer.
